# Grails dynamic rendering of map-injected g:select

Tags: grails, hashmap, html-select, gsp

I have the following Grails (2.3.6) controller:

```
class WidgetController {
    def index() {
        Map<String, List<String>> widgetMap = getSomehow()
        render (
            view: "widgets",
            model: [ widgetMapping: widgetMap ]
        )
    }
}
```

And the following GSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Omitting a bunch of stuff for brevity -->
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Widget Mappings</h3>

    <g:select name="widgetMapping" from="${widgetMapping}"/>
    <div id="widgetMapping">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to accomplish the following:

- For each key in the `widgets` map, display an `<option/>` in the dropdown `<select/>`
- When a user selects one of those <`option/>`s (or when the page first loads with the default option), the `<div id="widgetMapping">` section should be populated with a `<ul>` list, where each `<li>` in the list corresponds to one of the elements in the `List<String>` that the selected widget is mapped to

In other words, if the `widgetMap` (above, in the controller) looks like this at runtime:

```
Map<String, List<String>> widgetMap = []

List<String> colors = []
List<String> pets = []

colors << "Red"
colors << "Blue"
colors << "Green"

pets << "Dog"
pets << "Cat"

widgetMap.put("Colors", colors)
widgetMap.put("Pets", pets)
```

...then in the rendered HTML I would expect to see a `<select>` with 2 `<option>` children: "*Colors*" and "*Pets*". When you select "Colors" you should see a bulleted (`<ul>`) list enumerating "*Red*", "*Blue*", "*Green*"; and if you select "Pets" you would see any previous list clear and then display a list of "*Dog*" and "*Cat*" in its stead. Thus, making any new selection from the dropdown should clear the currently-displayed list and display the correct list for that option's respective key in the map.

Given the GSP code I have above, this behavior is simply not happening. Any ideas as to what I need to do?

Comment: GSP is not going to accomplish this alone. Have you written any Javascript to accomplish what you want? What is actually rendered when you try this?

Comment: Another thing that may just be a transcription error, you reference a variable `widgetMapping` in your GSP, but your controller sets a model variable `widgetMap`. While correcting this will help you along your way, it will still not solve your entire problem.

Comment: Thanks @rmlan - yes that was a transcription error (please see my update). Also, no, I have not written any JS code as I was hoping Grails might provide something like this out of the box. I have jQuery "installed" via asset pipeline - any ideas as to how I could accomplish this behavior with jQuery? Or even just raw JS? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have mentioned, you have a couple of different options.

1. Pass the entire map back to the client and store the values in a javascript value. I don't like this because it doesn't scale very well. In your example, you only have a couple of keys with a couple of values in each list, but this could grow pretty quickly, and I don't think you should necessarily be storing all of that data in memory on the client side.
2. Make subsequent Ajax calls to simply return the list for each key. This could be accomplished by listening for a `change` event on the drop-down, then replacing the contents of the div with a GSP rendered template. I like this option much better as it scales. Sure it makes more calls to the server, but the amount of data per call is minimal and your user experience will actually improve overall as the initial page-load will be reduced.

Controller:

```
class WidgetController {
    def index() {
        def widgetKeys = getSomehow()
        render (
            view: "widgets",
            model: [ widgets: widgetKeys ]
        )
    }

    def widgetList (String key) {
        def widgetList = getSomehow(key)
        render (
            template: "widgetTemplate",
            model: [ widgetList: widgetList ]
        )
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
    <g:each in="${widgetList}">
    <li>${it}</li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectId').on('change', function(){
        var select = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'widgetList', //might have to play with this so it is not hardcoded
            data: { 'key': select.value },
            success: function (list) {
                $('#widgetMapping').html(list);
            } 
        });
    })
});
```

I'm not guaranteeing that this will get you exactly what you want, but this should at least get you on the right track. There is a wealth of documentation for JQuery and several examples around the web, so I suggest you look around if you think you want to do something different.